# Intermittent OAuth failures for Google Drive API?

Tags: google-drive-api, google-oauth

I am writing an application which requests read+write access to Google Drive, and is restricted to only the folders my application creates. I am using the following scopes:

```
"https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.file",
"https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email"
```

I find that, intermittently (maybe 30% of the time), when users attempt to create a folder in Google Drive, I receive a 403 error: `Error 403: Insufficient Permission: Request had insufficient authentication scopes.`

Why would this be the case? Is there a circumstance where a user could successfully complete the OAuth flow, but the requested scopes would not be granted? When I test on my personal account, I don't even see an option to continue logging in while rejecting these scopes.

In my case, here is the relevant code snippet where I am getting a failure, in this case, in Go:

```
    import "google.golang.org/api/drive/v3"

    srv, _ := drive.New(client)  // client is of type *http.Client

    newFile := &drive.File{
        Name:     "My Folder Name",
        MimeType: "application/vnd.google-apps.folder",
        Parents:  []string{"root"},
    }

    file, err := srv.Files.Create(newFile).Fields("webViewLink", "id").Do()
    if err != nil {
        log.Println("Could not create google folder:", err.Error())
        return err
    }
```

Comment: I would go through your code and make sure you don't have a different scope hiding someplace or possibly be using old credentials for your user. That error message should only come if you say only requested read only access and then try to create a folder.

Comment: Do you always have “root” as the parent folder? Are you creating many folders?

Comment: Does your app have permission to write to your Drive root?